# Error: infinite rendering invalidation detected

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app with versions as follow:

```
DEBUG: Ember             : 3.0.0
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 3.0.2
DEBUG: jQuery            : 3.3.1
DEBUG: Ember Dialog      : 3.1.0
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.6.0
```

I have a route fetching data into a model, and that data is passed into a component. Whenever I add a closure action to this component, I get an

`Error: infinite rendering invalidation detected`

Whenever I remove the closure action code, everything works fine.

Route code:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend({
  currentUser: service('current-user'),

  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('account');
  },

  actions:{
    saveNewCustomer() {

    }
  }
});
```

Template causing error:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">{{t 'account.modals.new_customer.title'}}</h2>
    </div>

    {{account/customers/filter-accounts
            accounts=model
            currentUser=currentUser
            customerAdded=(action "saveNewCustomer")}}

</div>
```

Template working:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">{{t 'account.modals.new_customer.title'}}</h2>
    </div>

    {{account/customers/filter-accounts
            accounts=model
            currentUser=currentUser)}}

</div>
```

The code for the component is here:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  actions:{
    selectedAccount(account) {
      this.set('selectedAccount', account);
      this.toggleProperty('newCustomerModal');
    },

    toggleNewCustomerModal() {
      this.toggleProperty('newCustomerModal');
    },

    saveNewCustomer() {
      this.get('customerAdded')();
    },
  }
});
```

And the component template:

```
<div class="form-modal-content">
    <div class="el-input-wrap">
        <label class="el-input-label sr-only">Søk</label>
        {{input placeholder="Søk etter..." class="el-input"}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list-group">
    {{#each accounts as |account|}}
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            {{account.accountName}}<br>
            {{#each account.addresses as |address|}}
                {{address.displayAddressLine}}<br>
            {{/each}}
        </a>
    {{/each}}
</div>

{{#if newCustomerModal}}
    {{#modal-dialog
            close='toggleNewCustomerModal'
            targetAttachment="none"
            translucentOverlay=true}}
        <div class="modal-full">
            <form class="form-modal" {{action 'saveNewCustomer' on='submit'}}>
                <header class="form-modal-header">
                    <a title="Close" class="modal-close" href="#" {{action 'toggleNewCustomerModal'}}>{{fa-icon 'times'}}</a>
                    <h2>Legg til kunde</h2>
                </header>

                <div class="form-modal-content clearfix">
                    <h2>{{selectedAccount.accountName}}</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-full">
                    <button type="button" class="form-modal-button cancel" {{action 'toggleNewCustomerModal'}}>Avbryt</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="form-modal-button">Lagre</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
```

I am not sure if this is an idiotic error made by me that I just can not see, or if there is a bug. I believe the former.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `saveNewCustomer ` defined? Note that the action helper will lookup the action on the current controller not the route. If you want to implement your actions in your route, use this addon https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper

Comment: @GerDner Oh my, I somehow completely forgot about not having actions on the route. I have been using route actions on another project and just gotten so used to it. Creating a controller and move the actions there solved the issue. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Move the action the controller or use an addon like https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper will solve the problem.

Original Comment: Where is saveNewCustomer defined? Note that the action helper will lookup the action on the current controller not the route. If you want to implement your actions in your route, use this addon

Comment: I went with moving the action to the controller. After reading a lot about controllers getting removed some time in the future, I tried to avoid them. But this seems to not being the case anymore, so I am not so reluctant to use controllers anymore. I guess the talk now is to use components.

Comment: Controller will be deprecated sometime. I think it will come with routable components.